# Call two functionalities at the same time in single click event

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here I'm trying to call the two functionalities in a single click event. I have tried by passing the two functionalities in click event by separated by " ; " but the second one is getting triggered rather than the first one where I need to trigger the both events functionalities at the same time. Here I have attached the code for reference. So kindly help me out

```
<li title="xplane" title="yplane"  class="nav-link"
            (click)="createsectionclip('xplane')" (click)="createsectionclip('yplane')">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img [src]="xclipSvg" title="xplane" [src]="yclipSvg" title="yplane"
                    class="img-border img-width mx-auto" style="cursor:pointer" width="32px" height="32px"> </a>
        </li>
        <hr class='seperator-inline-dashed' />
        <li title="yplane" class="nav-link" (click)="createsectionclip('yplane')">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <img [src]="yclipSvg" title="yplane"
                    class="img-border img-width mx-auto" style="cursor:pointer" width="32px" height="32px"> </a>
        </li> 

  public createsectionclip(title: string) {
    title = title.toLowerCase();
    const that = this;
    let imgSvg;
    let dd = "none";

    if (title === that._name) {
      if (this.showsectionclip) {
        imgSvg = that.activeClipping;
      } else {
        imgSvg = that.sectionclipSvg;
      } dd = title;

    } else if (title === 'xplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeXPlane;
    } else if (title === 'yplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeYPlane;
    } else if (title === 'zplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeZPlane;
    } else if (title === 'xnplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeXNPlane;
    } else if (title === 'ynplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeYNPlane;
    } else if (title === 'znplane') {

      imgSvg = that.activeZNPlane;
    } else {

      imgSvg = that.sectionclipSvg;
    }
    this.showsectionclip = !this.showsectionclip;
    that.clippingBtnSvg = imgSvg;

    if ((imgSvg !== "none") && (title !== that._name)) {
      dd = title;
    }
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('sectionclip', {
      bubbles: false,
      detail: dd
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Try (onclick)="createsectionclip('xplane');createsectionclip('yplane')"
They will be called one bye one (not at the same time).

Comment: Do you mean:
<li title="xplane" title="yplane"  class="nav-link"
            onclick="createsectionclip('xplane');createsectionclip('yplane');">

Comment: Or wrap the two function calls in another function to use in `(click)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create another method for both `xplane` and `yplane`.

```
public createBothsectionclip() {
  createsectionclip('xplane');
  createsectionclip('yplane');
}
```

And only call the above method on a click. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<li title="xplane" title="yplane"  class="nav-link" (click)="createBothsectionclip()">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img [src]="xclipSvg" title="xplane" [src]="yclipSvg" title="yplane" class="img-border img-width mx-auto" style="cursor:pointer" width="32px" height="32px">
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded so I am not sure how you could run them simultaneously. I would try to do something like this:

In the li element:

```
(click)="InvokeFunctions()"
```

And the function will then call those you want to run at the same time:

```
function InvokeFunctions(){
   createsectionclip('xplane');
   createsectionclip('yplane')
}
```

This could work, but for a nicer solution have a look at JavaScript Web Worker.

Comment: I tried that out but only the functionality of second event is being getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

As others already answered, the best you can do is to wrap those two functions into a single one which then handles the **click** event. However, they cannot be executed *simoultaneously*: the first one will get executed first, then the second one will run.
Thus, make sure the first function doesn't negatively affect the outcome of the second and be also aware that, if they act on the same thing, only the effects of the second function might be visible (as the work of the first one might get overridden/redone).

Comment: Is there any possibilty to overcome that one

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?